# Html video not playing in android webview It is working Well in android chrome

Tags: java, android, flash, webview, flash-player-11

I want to run **live videos** on my App using webview Video having html website,**Video is working fine in mobile Googlechrome** but it is **not working in mobile Inbuilt browser**. YouTube is working well in webview but Live Video URL is not working.I guess I need flash to run this video.**How can I download Flash as I had seen the last flash was 11.1 and now not getting any flash for android**.

URL: pattern ("http://example.com/player/player.html");

Here is my Code:

```
    webView = (VideoEnabledWebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/cache");
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases");
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new InsideWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://example.com/player/player.html");
```

Appreciate for solution.

Comment: `I need flash to run this`  you likely don't. You can't use flash in a webView.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko then How will I run live video in my webview?Youtube is working well in webview.And Live video is working well in android Google Chrome App.

Comment: in general video does work in webView. Probably *your video* has something specific, that can't be handled by webview. If you want help, you will have to post some details about the video you want to play.

Comment: it doesn't work for me even in a desktop browser. Probably there is a problem with a stream itself.

Comment: But May be possible it will not work outside India and other thing it is working fine in my pc.and in mobile chrome also.

Comment: If it doesn't work outside India, I don't think I can help you. In general, not all video types/formats/streams work in WebView. Probably it is a better idea to play the stream directly, not through the WebView.

Comment: I want to use RTSP streaming in webview but unable to do that...@VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: Is there any other way to display video in WebView @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: in general, video works just fine in the WebView. But your video is special somehow, and nobody except you knows how exactly it is.

Comment: Are you using Safari or Chrome?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169140/discussion-between-abhishek-bardolia-and-vladyslav-matviienko).